# Writing my own function

Tags: r

I am a beginner at R and trying my hand at writing an R function. The function which I wrote is like this

```
male <- c(1:10)
female <- c(11:20)
msum <- function(h,j) {
for(i in 1:length(h)){ 
     e <- c()
    e[i] = h[i] + j[i]
    i = i+1
}
e
}
```

now when I call the function by `p <- msum(male, female)` , I look for an output as a vector of length 10 with result as sum of male and female vectors but what I get is a vector of length 10 with `NA` as the value in first 9 positions and 30 as the last value of the vector. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: This is a scoping issue. You defined `e` inside for loop but used it outside the loop

Comment: You also don't need to increment `i`, so remove the line `i = i+1`

Comment: Also, it can be very confusing practice to name functions the same as base R functions (`sum` already exists).

Comment: How about just `mysum <- function(h, j) h + j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

```
male <- c(1:10)
female <- c(11:20)

msum <- function(h,j) {
  e <- c()
  for(i in 1:length(h)){ 

    e[i] = h[i] + j[i]
  }
  e
}
msum(male, female)

[1] 12 14 16 18 20 22 24 26 28 30
```

Comment: `e`'s memory should be allocated beforehand if possible, and it can here.  `e <- integer(length(h))` instead of `e  <- c()`

Answer (score 0):

I could be missing something, but I don't know that you need a user-defined function for this example:

```
male + female
```

Although I suppose you could wrap it into a function:

```
vect_sum <- function(vec1, vec2) {
    vec1 + vec2
}
vect_sum(male, female)
```